Docker cannot extract image
I just update my ubuntu and its kernel has been updated:
> uname -r
6.8.0-40-generic

Then, I pull a simple image:
docker pull alpine:latest

And I got the following error:
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
c6a83fedfae6: Extracting [==================================================>]  3.623MB/3.623MB
failed to register layer: exit status 22: unpigz: abort: zlib version less than 1.2.3

However, this is the version of zlib:
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.2).

I just downgrade the kernel version to 6.5.x, however the problem is not solved.
what is wrong with new ubuntu update?

Offtopic for SO. Your question is not about software development or programming. Ask a moderator to move it to e.g. superuser.com

I just install the zlib from source and the issue is resolved. For this configuration, I use 1.3.1 version.
Here, how to install zlib from source:
git clone https://github.com/madler/zlib.git -b v1.3.1
cd zlib
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo make install


To improve your answer, you could add how you installed it from source.

please, could you  explain how you install zlib from source?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It's a horrible idea to install a library from source on a system that has a package manager (e.g. Ubuntu).

I am so curious about your docker images size? @AKX

@mobejani I'm not sure I'm following there. Also note that Alpine images, although small, can occasionally be buggy and/or a lot slower than glibc based images.

@AKX I appreciate for your note about alpine image, but it just a example. I believe that the building from source for large library and using multi-stage docker build can decrease your image size significantly (do not compile them in share manner). Also in most of the time package managers are not updated to LTS and you have to do so.

Do you believe that, or have you measured it? Have you considered the time it takes to build a large library from source? Besides: the unpigz error occurs outside the container (when Docker is trying to decompress an image layer), and your answer here implies installing zlib from source onto the host system, so I'm not sure how your comment applies.

Yes, I have measure. The practice that I consider is that first some basic images are created (You notice that they may take time), that they rarely are rebuilt (they contains some vital library). For each application I just convey the part of the basic image that I want. As an instance, I can compress flashlight image from 12GB to 2GB.
flashlight repo

Also, you mentioned building from source is horrible idea. In my opinion, this statement is not true. Most of the time the package manager like apt does not have latest stable version (for example there is critical security problem) and you have to compile it from source or compiled version in (etc. from github release section of library).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No, I said building + installing from source like you do, on a system managed by a package manager, is a horrible idea. (Inside containers, it's an entirely different thing, you do you.) If you were to build a new version of the same package using the tools provided by your distro (see e.g. here) and then (e.g.) dpkg -i the package, that'd be more okay. Doing sudo make install will replace distro-provided files with "random" ones.

This issue of compatibility, Need to install zlib specific version:
sudo apt-get install zlib1g=1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.5 

You also check other versions:
apt-cache policy zlib1g
zlib1g:
  Installed: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.5
  Candidate: 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.5
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.5 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages


docker extract not only use unpigz，but also use gzip，pigz speed is surpass gzip when server have multiple cpus，So if you want solve the issue quickly,
just remove pigz from you system,docker will use gzip to extract image automatic.
sudo apt-get remove pigz  # Debian/Ubuntu
sudo yum remove pigz      # CentOS/RHEL

also you can upgrade you pigz to solve the problem.
